# Entity Framework - Why does this Linq query generate multiple round trips?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, query-optimization

I have 3 tables:  `Product`, `Category`, and `ProductCategory`, where `ProductCategory` is the join table for a many-to-many relationship between `Product` and `Category`.  The following Linq query (which is an extension method in the `Category` class) results in a round-trip for each `ProductCategory` record within the current `Category`.  Why is this?  How can this be improved?  Also note that this is database-first EF.

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> ActiveProducts
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ProductCategories.Where(c => !c.Product.IsDeleted && c.Product.IsActive).OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder).Select(c => c.Product);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation properties are not `IQueryable`, alas. That's why you get a LINQ-to-Objects query.

Comment: Understood, but how do I go about slimming this down to a single round-trip?

Comment: You need access to the ObjectContext so that you can build a normal query that encompasses everything at once. You have to pass in the ObjectContext.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  I'd like to have a nice read-only property named "ActiveProducts" instead of a method requiring an instance of my context.  Are you sure there's no work-around?

Comment: @Keith this is a design flaw in EF, IMHO. L2S had the same problem, and it was a very nicely thought out ORM (now deprecated). So maybe there is a reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

With Linq, the default is to fetch the data on each iteration of the enumerable.  If you want to fetch all rows at once, call .ToList() on the query.  That appears to be the more favorable approach.

Comment: Already tried that:  `return this.ProductCategories.Where(c => !c.Product.IsDeleted && c.Product.IsActive).OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder).Select(c => c.Product).ToList();` still results in multiple round-trips.

Comment: Looks like usr's answer is accurate.  Using the navigation property c.Product is causing it to do multiple round trips.  Maybe there is a way to refactor it to some type of join?  not sure how that will work with extension methods.